# finding a span with value greater than the text using xpath in selenium

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am using selenium webdriver for automating tests.

I have a set of span elements on a webpage like this .

```
 <span data-template="" data-test-id="20161126092010078480788" 
 class="">8.2</span>
```

I want to find all the span elements which have text > 5.
Can any one help me build an appropraite xpath for the same?.
Note: the data-test-id attribute is same for all the spans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one should work

```
//span[number(.) > 5]
```

Comment: It does, indeed Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Could you please tell me what's the meaning of the dot inside? Is that a regular expression?

Comment: @Mugen, It denotes the text (ignoring the tags)

Comment: @AjaySuwalka Maybe dot here refers to the current object I'm thinking

Comment: It's kind of text(), but text() gives the text content of only that particular tag but not the childs. dot ignores all the tags inside an element and gives the text

Answer (score -1):

```
<span class="a-price-whole">79,999</span>
<span class="a-price-whole">89,999</span>
<span class="a-price-whole">59,999</span>
<span class="a-price-whole">76,999</span>
```

xpath to find amount greater than 75000:

```
//*[number(translate(., ',', '')) > 75000]
```

output:

```
79999, 89999, 76999
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).